# Validate email address with multi level domains in PHP with RegEx

Tags: php, regex

Need to validate email address with single domain level or multi level domains.(actually domain level <=4)

**Criteria:**

- Email (username) should start with letter[a-z] and it may have numbers but not for 1st letter and periods(.) **No other characters**.
- After @ sign every domain should start with letter.(minimum length 2)
- Maximum domains <= 4 .

> Ex: email@my.sub.mail.com

above example there 4 domains;

- .*my*
- .*sub*
- .*mail*
- .*com*

I try with this RegEx:

```
^[a-zA-Z](:?[a-zA-Z0-9._-])+(@[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-])+\.+(([a-zA-Z]){2,6})$
```

But above regex not validating multiple domains correctly.It's only get 1 domain. 
  Ex: myemail@gmail.com

Online Regex : https://regex101.com/r/7SXS1Z/1

Comment: Try [`^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.){1,4}[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$`](https://regex101.com/r/7SXS1Z/2)

Comment: `filter_var()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`???

Comment: I've done this one filter_var($s_email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

Comment: @AbraCadaver I need to validate something like this->  000@example.com.jp so if I used FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL itself it's says above email also valid technically.

Comment: Because that is a valid email, so you only want to accept certain valid emails...

Comment: Hence mentioned rules... @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 1):

Your regex applies much more rules in accepting an email address. E.g. allowing email addresses to include more than one `@` symbol. Go as simple as your own rules:

```
^[a-z][^@]*@(([a-z][a-z0-9-]+)\.){0,3}(?2)$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q6R9y3/1)

Comment: Can you explain this part [^@]*@

Comment: Yes, it means any character except a `@` up to a `@`.

Comment: Need `i` modifier if you're not using `A-Z`

Comment: It wasn't significant to note but I have set it in live demo already. @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for

```
^
[a-zA-Z][-.\w]*       # before @
@
[a-zA-Z][-.\w]+       # first subdomain
(?:
    \.[a-zA-Z][-.\w]+ # eventually others
){1,3}
$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7SXS1Z/3).

Comment: You are ignoring email addresses with dots `.` and dashes `-` in user/domain names.